# Android SIP Registration Port Unreachable

Tags: android, sip

I am trying to make a sip call by using android.net.sip but have registration problem.
All responses from the server (I tried multiple servers) correctly reached UDP port number that is described in the Via and Contact headers of the Register.
However, all of responses got ICMP port unreachable.

I am using AVD running on XP machine and I verified both isAPIsupproted and isVoipSupported.

I would appreciate if you can provide a solution.

Comment: Does your XP machine have a valid global address? Are incoming connection filtered?

Comment: It has valid local address and the servers are also in same subnet, so there is no router in between the servers and Android sip. I also disabled the firewall and other protections but no changes made.

Comment: Does it work with a real device? If so, must be something about how the emulator handles incoming connections.

Comment: I tested 2 real android phones, droid-x and droid-pro that have updated to 2.3 but both of them returned false from isApiSupported. So I have not been able to drive the sip classes on actual device.

Comment: It seems the emulator only listens on the loopback interface (check with netstat, etc.), so if you want to get incmoing connections, you need to portforward incoming connections on the host machine's LAN interface (eth0, etc.) to the corresponding ports on loopback. I haven't tried this though, so it's all theoretical.

Comment: Thanks very very much! Your comment was correct. I set "redir" on the emulator console and then 200OKs for Registers were accepted. (onRegistrationDone was called)

Answer (score 0):

Does the response packet reach the port which REGISTER packet sent from?

Comment: Source port in the UDP header and port number in SIP (Via and Contact Headfer) are different.

Comment: Servers I tested responded 200OK to the port that is described in SIP headers. I also tested other sip UA and all of them set same port number in UDP and SIP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the emulator only listens on the loopback interface (check with netstat, etc.), so if you want to get incoming connections, you need to port forward incoming connections on the host machine's LAN interface (eth0, etc.) to the corresponding ports on loopback. I haven't tried this though, so it's all theoretical.